# Losing Reputation For What Seems Like No Reason

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Recently I have noticed that my account will just lose like 2 reputation at a time. I will go into my `Profile Overview` and click on `Reputation` and look at the recent days and I can't find anything that states why I am losing this reputation. This is not a huge deal for me, I was just curious if anyone has been seeing this as well and if you could shed some light on to it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

That will be when a question that you have edited has been deleted. It happens to me still occasionally. It is just part of the experience of participating here. Once you get above 2000 rep you no longer have any reputation gain for accepted edits as they no longer go for approval.

To make reputation losses from deleted posts visible you have to tick the show removed posts checkbox. Reputation losses from downvotes or an answer being changed from accepted or unaccepted will always show.

[image: -2 reputation]

Comment: Thanks Dave, I checked the box on the reputation page that says `Show Removed` and then I could see them. Thanks.